# Visual Studio 2019 builds 32bit executable when configuration is 64bit

Tags: c#, visual-studio, x86, 64-bit, visual-studio-2019

I am attempting to build an executable from a C# project in Visual Studio 2019. The project configuration is Debug - x64 and the target platform is set to x64 as well. I have double checked the settings in the Build Settings, the Configuration Manager

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkZnH.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oh2qN.png]

and in the [`.csproj` file itself](https://pastebin.com/rHsRSxkT).

I have also checked that I am on a x64 machine (Windows 10 x64).

When starting the build, Visual Studio says
`Build started: Project: MyProject, Configuration: Debug x64`.

However, the executable created is 32 bit. I have checked the file and when attempting to debug, the debugger also shows a Win32 executable.

I have tried to clean the project multiple times, restarted Visual Studio and the computer, nothing changes. Another project that is contained in the same project map as the C# project, which is a C++ project that is used to build a .dll does build with x64. So I am assuming it is a problem specific to the one project. Is there some internal caching stuff going on that might cause this?

EDIT:

According to this https://superuser.com/questions/358434/how-to-check-if-a-binary-is-32-or-64-bit-on-windows, I am checking by opening my .exe file with notepad which shows me PE L = 32 bit.
Also, when running the executable from VS with the Start button an Debug - x64 configuration, this is the output:

`'ProjMapping.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'D:\[...]\ProjMapping\bin\Debug\ProjMapping.exe'.`

The project I am attempting to create a x64 executable from is ProjMapping

When I am clicking on Build, Rebuild or Start (on the top) I am getting the 32 bit executable created in the output directory.

Comment: Can you show us configuration settings for `.csproj`. How are you checking the executable is of `x64` or `x32` bit. Let us know the steps. I would like to reproduct this issue on my machine. I guess you are checking configuration of some other project but before making this conclusion I would like to reproduce this issue

Comment: Not reproducing on my machine, I can see `PE d†` when I open `.exe` file in `Notepad++`